# Hide Import-Module output from TFS Release logs

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am using TFS 2015 Release. I have a very simple script: it imports module and runs another script. The problem is I see `Import-Module` logs in TFS Release log and I cannot hide them. Example:

```
# ScriptRunner.ps1
Import-Module MyModule -DisableNameChecking -Global
& ".\script.ps1"
```

When I run this locally by using below command, I don't see any output from `Import-Module` command:

```
powershell "path\ScriptRunner.ps1"
```

In TFS Release I have "PowerShell on Target Machines" task, and I run the same script `ScriptRunner.ps1`. And this is what I see in the log:

```
Deployment started on target machine...
Loading module from path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyModule\MyModule.psm1'
Exporting function 'My-Function-1'.
...
Exporting function 'My-Function-10'.
The 'My-Function-1' command in the MyModule module was imported, but because its name does not include an approved verb, it might be difficult to find. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
The command name 'My-Function-1' from the module 'MyModule' contains one or more of the following restricted characters: # , ( ) { } [ ] & - / \ $ ^ ; : " ' < > | ? @ ` * % + = ~
Importing function 'My-Function-1'.
...
```

How is this getting logged? I specify DisableNameChecking flag. I tried to hide this messages by changing `Import-Module` line in my script, but this doesn't help:

```
[void](Import-Module MyModule -DisableNameChecking -Global)
Import-Module MyModule -DisableNameChecking -Global | Out-Null
Import-Module MyModule -DisableNameChecking -Global -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: I wasn't able to check, but if I remember correctly, the messages are 'warnings', which you can hide using the `-WarningAction` parameter:  `Import-Module MyModule -WarningAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: @boxdog Tried this, but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the `-Verbose:$false` parameter to the `Import-Module` call :

```
Import-Module MyModule -DisableNameChecking -Global -Verbose:$false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of $ErrorActionPreference flag to Silentlycontinue. That should fix the issue.
Please be aware that when you add this line to the script the whole script change the Error Action Preference.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Silentlycontinue"
```

Comment: These messages are warnings, not errors. My current $ErrorActionPreference is "Stop", and script is working.